# Trouble importing environment anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a yml file that I'm trying to import via the Anaconda Navigator but having no luck. I don't get an error message, it just runs forever without actually ever importing the environment. I have administrator privileges on this pc, but it is a work pc. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for things I might try to get this to work?

Here's the file:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip
  - jupyter
  - pandas
  - matplotlib
  - scikit-learn=0.22
  - openpyxl
  - statsmodels
  - py-xgboost
  - saravji::pmdarima
  - requests
  - lxml
  - pypdf2
  - rtree
  - fiona
  - shapely
  - descartes
  - folium
  - plotly
  - pyproj
  - geopandas
  - pip:
      - geovoronoi
```

Comment: does it ever complete? how large is this environment file? some operations can take many minutes to resolve

Comment: Without debugging details or basic description of context plus the YAML this is too open-ended. Voting to close.

Comment: I can't share the actual yaml file but it is large. That being said, I've let it run for hours without interruption and it never completes. Happy to add more details here, let me know what's needed

Answer (score 0):

1. make yourself familiar with `conda` on the commandline. To import an environment that was before exported into a .yaml file, use

```
conda env create --file my-env.yml
```

If your `conda` isn't in your path, you can use the `Anaconda-Navigator` to start a terminal with the base environment active by using the green button marked in the image in the `Environments` / `base` section of `Anaconda-Navigator`. There you can use the command.

[image]

You will see in more detail what is happening on the commandline.

2. `Conda` can get awfully slow with resolving conflicts in larger environments. The [Mamba solver](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community), written in c++ (instead of python like the original `Conda`) is much faster and that may help a lot in cases like this. Even the `mamba` solver may take his time, but i have seen `Conda` taking hours to finish.
3. The `Mamba` solver is the solver from the [mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project, which is a drop-in replacement of `Conda` written in c++, and therefore much faster than the original `Conda`. So, i recommend using `Mamba` over the original `Conda`. It is much faster than `Conda`. You can install it into an existing `Conda`-installation, and although it is not the recomanded way, it might be much easier to do so if there is an existing `Conda` installation that you like to keep. The recommended Way is to use the `Mambaforge` installer or the `micromamba` executable.
4. If you actually decide to ditch the `Anaconda`-installation and start with a fresh `Mamabforge`-installation, but still like to have the comfort of  the `Anaconda-Navigator`, you can install the `Anaconda-Navigator` alongside of `Mamba`, but *don't* clutter your base env with it. Instead, install `Anaconda-Navigator` into it's own environment using

```
mamba create -n anaconda-navigator anaconda-navigator -c anaconda
```

This will install `Anaconda-Navigator` into its own Environment (as `Anaconda`-distribution itself should have done, but sadly didn't). Fun part: You will see the `Anaconda-Navigator` environment when listed on the Commandline with

```
conda env list
```

but not inside the `Anaconda-Navigator`, it's hiding itself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed reply. I tried your first suggestion using conda to import the file, and the 'Collecting package metadata (report.json)' step completed, but it seems to be hung up on the 'Solving environment' step. I'm doing this as part of a course and they seem to be adamant that I follow the Anaconda installation so I'm hesitant to attempt the mamba solver - especially if the issue is not with the size of the environment.

Comment: Is it possible to manually re-create an environment based on the contents of the yml file? Sorry if that's a dumb question but I'm very new to this and seems like that might be a straight-forward solution.

Comment: how long is your yml file? Maybe just append it to your question

Comment: ok append above

Comment: Of course you can create a conda environment with just a python version inside of it with `conda create --name myenv python=3.7`, then activate that environment and install one package after the otehr with commands like
`conda install jupyter`.  you should not need to install pip, as pip should get installed along with python, and your last file `geovoronoi` should not get installed by conda but by pip with `pip install geovoronoi`

Comment: But here some comments:
That .yml tries to create an environment with python 3.7. Python 3.7 had reached end of life at 2023-06-27. This is an outdated python version. Current recomended python versions are 3.9 or 3.10, which are both rock solid established versions, whereas the brand new 3.12 might have some stability lacks, some lacks in support of libraries etc. Even 3.8 is still supported, but 3.7 is dead.

Comment: but since the course seems to be based on rather outdated material, I would recommend you to very confidently throw the whistle on precepts that are clearly outdated - and to rely on up-to-date solutions yourself from the beginning. So don't use the old Python3.7, but 3.10 or even 3.11.
And do use Mamba instead of Anaconda - with Anaconda-Navigator, which is much easier to get started with than the command line.

Comment: btw: Slightly diverging from the original materials has been proven to be ***much*** more efficient for ones personal learning success.

Comment: Okay - I have no problem diverging, I'm just new to Anaconda and relatively new using different environments for different tasks so want to ensure everything works. I'll go ahead and manually create a new environment using python 3.11 then manually install the other packages (hopefully without encountering issues doing so) and if have issues with them all playing well together down the road I'll address it at that point.

Comment: You should try mamba

Comment: Haha okay with two recommendations I will look into mamba as well. Thank you for the help